# How to refer to a random integer in R.raw method in Android?

Tags: android, refer

I have this code

```
Random x = new Random(44);
int l = x.nextInt();
int path = R.raw.l;
```

I know it doesn't work that way,but it explains my situation the most.
i.e. Providing l==5, i want to use R.raw.5 as the path. however, R.raw seems to understand only straightforward values, not the referred ones.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get `int` indentifier from your activity with this code:

```
Random x = new Random(44);
int l = x.nextInt();
int path = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(l), "raw", getPackageName());
```

More info in documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29